# Passing args to class method Ruby

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm newbie in Jekyll, Ruby. I'm trying to create my custom plugin for Jekyll. So far my code below. I don't understand Ruby compiler behavior, now this code doesn't work, with error `undefined method scan`, but if I place everything from `parse` to `initialize` instead of `parse(text)`, then it starts working.

Complete error: `Liquid Exception: undefined method 'scan' for #<Liquid::Tokenizer:0x005577b047a220> in index.html`

```ruby
module Jekyll
  class CreatePicTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      parse(text)
    end

    def parse(text)
      pattern = /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/
      @class = text.scan(pattern)[0]
      @alt = text.scan(pattern)[1]
      @path = text.scan(pattern)[2]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: please add complete error stack trace

Comment: You can shorten the assignment: `@class, @alt, @path = text.scan(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I place everything from `parse` to `initialize` instead of `parse(text)`, then it starts working

If you can't extract some simple code into a method, something else must be going on.

In this specific case, you are overwriting Liquid's built-in [`parse`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/4369fe6c85038d50e9f75f1405c26b4214d15f2c/lib/liquid/tag.rb#L8) method. This method is called internally, so the error you are seeing is caused by Liquid, not by your own call. Unless you are trying to alter Liquid's parsing, you should not implement that method yourself. Liquid needs this method to work properly.

The easiest fix is to simply rename your method, e.g.:

```
require 'liquid'

class CreatePicTag < Liquid::Tag
  def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
    super
    parse_text(text)
  end

  def parse_text(text)
    pattern = /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/
    @class = text.scan(pattern)[0]
    @alt   = text.scan(pattern)[1]
    @path  = text.scan(pattern)[2]
  end

  def render(context)
    [@class, @alt, @path].join('|')
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('create_pig', CreatePicTag)
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("{% create_pig [foo][bar][baz] %}")
p @template.render
```

Output:

```
foo|bar|baz
```

Answer (score 3):

Verify whether the text has any `scan` method on it before calling it:

```
module Jekyll
  class CreatePicTag < Liquid::Tag
    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      parse(text)
    end

    def parse(text)
      pattern = /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/
      if text.respond_to?(:scan)
        @class = text.scan(pattern)[0]
        @alt = text.scan(pattern)[1]
        @path = text.scan(pattern)[2]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and call it like this:

```
Jekyll::CreatePicTag.new(tag_name, text, tokens)
```

Comment: You can't call a class method (`parse`) from an instance method (`initialize`), can you?

Comment: Are the instance variables being defined on the instance or the class?

Comment: @Stefan you are right, code updated accordingly. Instance variables are defined on the instance.

Comment: But why does it work (according to OP) when putting the code right into `initialize`?

Comment: @Stefan checked your answer, thanks I understood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`scan` is a method defined on the `String` class.
The `undefined method 'scan'` means that at times, the local variable is something other than a `String`.

So, you can modify the `parse` method slightly to ensure that *`text` is always a `String`*:

```
def parse(text)
  text = text.to_s
  pattern = /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/

  @class = text.scan(pattern)[0]
  @alt = text.scan(pattern)[1]
  @path = text.scan(pattern)[2]
end
```

Comment: Follow up question: _"why is my template parsing broken?"_. (calling `to_s` to convert a `Liquid::Tokenizer` to a string might not solve the actual problem)

Comment: I agree with you.. and love your answer.